# How to use a SOAP API with login and session codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, soap

I have a set of soap APIs which can perform actions like login,logout,keepalive,access other several resources.Inorder to access the other resources,I have to pass a session id which I got from the login api.The session gets time out in 5minutes.
I am confused on how to make this working.

I am using codeigniter for my project,and I have built one library with the set of soap api requests defined in it.

```
class Soap_api
{
    function __construct()
    {

        define("UID",     "myuser");
        define("PWD",    "34rf3a45575");
        define("API_ENDPOINT", "http://uat-api.testingsoapapi.in/services/smp");
        define("PRODUCT_CODE", "24");
        $resp = $this->keepAliveLib();
        if($resp['ResponseCode'] == '0')
        {
            define("SessionID",$resp['SessionID']);
        }

    }
    function keepAliveLib()
    {
        $resp = $this->login();
        return $resp;
    }
    function one
    {
     //This function needs the sessionID receieved from login function
     }
    function two
    {
     //This function needs the sessionID receieved from login function
     }
```

So when ever any of the functions from this class is accessed,the constructor calls the keepAliveLib which calls the login function residing in this class and return the session id to the constructor function and set it as global constant sessionID .So the function which I called will be using the that session ID which is made as a constant.

Is this the standard way of calling APIs which relay on sessions?The login function is called when ever a function is called and creates a different session ID.There is a function `keepAlive` in the library which can be used to maintaining the session,but instead of using keepAlive , Im logging each time a function in this is accessed.

Is there anything wrong in this flow?Can this be done in some other ways?

Answer (score 0):

ok i'm probably not understanding this fully but would this work?

```
    $resp = $this->keepAliveLib();
    if($resp['ResponseCode'] == '0') {

        $this->sessionid = $resp['SessionID']); }

    else { // fail gracefully }
```

**$this->sessionid** is now available to any method in the controller.